# Let $|\mathbb F|=q$ where $\mathbb F$ is a field. Then $|GL_n(\mathbb F)|=(q^n-1)(q^n-q)(q^n-q^2)\ldots(q^n-q^{n-1})$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $|\mathbb F|=q$ where $\mathbb F$ is a field. Now
>
> $$|GL_n(\mathbb F)|=(q^n-1)(q^n-q)(q^n-q^2)\ldots(q^n-q^{n-1}).$$

How it is so?

**My attempt**

I just viewed in the matrix such that 
$\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
a_{11}&a_{12}&\cdots&a_{1n-1}&a_{1n}\\
\vdots&&\vdots&&\vdots\\
a_{n1}&a_{n2}&\cdots&a_{nn-1}&a_{nn}
\end{array}\right)$

For the first element I will have q choices and rest of the elements also have q choices. So there are $q^n$ choices and i should neglect $0$ in all at a time. So I removed one choice from the total so for the first row I will have $q^n-1$ choices. But for the second and third i am having confusion how to see the choices. And I am thinking that this will give the number of distinct basis for $GL_n(\mathbb F)$. Is it correct. Give me a diagrammatical explanation.

Comment: It is not true that there are no zeroes in the matrix!

Comment: why there are zeroes in the first row itself.@Mariano

Comment: I did not say that there *are* zeroes: I said that there can be zeroes. For example the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ is one of those you are trying to count.

Comment: ya..@MarianoSuárez-Alvarez

Comment: Kindly somebody give me diagrammatically..

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate. Notice that the linked question is probably only one of many ones which have a complete proof. You can find it even on Wikipedia. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_group

Answer (score 1):

Hint: We want to choose $n$ linearly independent vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ in $\mathbb{F}^n$. For $v_1$ we can choose any non-zero vector, so we have $q^n-1$ choices. For $v_2$ we can choose any vector which is not a multiple of $v_1$, so we have $q^n-q$ choices (since $q_1 \neq 0$). For $v_3$ we can choose any vector which is not in the span of $v_1,v_2$, and since $v_1,v_2$ are linearly independent, this rules out exactly $q^2$ vectors, leaving $q^n-q^2$ choices. And so on.

Comment: ya.. but how $q^n-q$. that what i am asking@Yuval

Comment: why dont it $q^n-2$

Comment: Since there are $q$ multiples of $v_1$: $0,v_1,2v_1,\ldots,(q-1)v_1$, and they are all different. You have to rule out all of them.

Comment: oh then similarly we will have q multiples of $v_1$ as well as $v_2$ thats we are substracting $q^2$ in the next case right??@Yuval

Comment: I think at this point you can try a few examples to see what's going on. Try to work on it on your own for a while, and only if you still can't see what's going on, ask further questions here.

Comment: k.. thank you.. so much.. i will try for simple matrix..@Yuval